# Create a scholarship roster out of a list of players via Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Recently, I was able to scrape out a college football roster from [the following website](https://gopsusports.com/sports/football/roster/2021) and I was able to get the following output below...

```
    Number  Name    Position    Experience  Height  Weight  Hometown / High School  Previous School High School Hometown
0   0.0 Jonathan Sutherland S   R-Sr.   5-11    203 Ottawa, Ontario, Canada / Episcopal (Va.)   NaN Episcopal (Va.) Ottawa, Ontario, Canada
1   1.0 Jaquan Brisker  S   Sr.+    6-1 204 Pittsburgh, Pa. / Gateway   Lackawanna College  Gateway Pittsburgh, Pa.
2   2.0 Keaton Ellis    CB  Jr. 5-11    192 State College, Pa. / State College Area NaN State College Area  State College, Pa.
3   2.0 Ta'Quan Roberson    QB  R-So.   5-11    199 Orange, N.J. / DePaul Catholic  NaN DePaul Catholic Orange, N.J.
4   3.0 Johnny Dixon    CB  Jr. 6-0 188 Tampa, Fla. / Chamberlain   South Carolina  Chamberlain Tampa, Fla.
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
104 NaN Jaylen Reed S   Fr. 6-0 213 Detroit, Mich. / Martin Luther King High School NaN Martin Luther King High School  Detroit, Mich.
105 NaN Jordan van den Berg DT  So. 6-3 292 Johannesburg, South Africa / Providence Christ...   Iowa Western    Providence Christian Academy    Johannesburg, South Africa
106 NaN Harrison Wallace III    WR  Fr. 6-1 187 Montgomery, Ala. / Pike Road High School    NaN Pike Road High School   Montgomery, Ala.
107 NaN Zakee Wheatley  CB  Fr. 6-2 190 Crofton, Md. / Archbishop Spalding High School  NaN Archbishop Spalding High School Crofton, Md.
108 NaN Eric Wilson OL  Sr.+    6-4 320 Minnetrista, Minn. / Benilde-St. Margaret's Harvard Benilde-St. Margaret's  Minnetrista, Minn.
109 rows × 10 columns
```

...from the following script.

```
roster = pd.read_html('https://gopsusports.com/sports/football/roster/2021')

roster_final = roster[2]

roster_final.columns = ['Number', 'Name', 'Position', 'Experience', 'Height', 'Weight', 'Hometown / High School', 'Previous School']

roster_final['High School'] = roster_final['Hometown / High School'].str.split('/').str[-1]
roster_final['Hometown'] = roster_final['Hometown / High School'].str.split('/').str[0]

roster_final
```

What I want to do now is to create what is known as a "scholarship grid" where the roster is broken down by position AND how long they have been a part of the program. An example of a scholarship grid comes [from this webpage](https://www.roarlionsroar.com/penn-state-football/scholarship-grid).

I have given it a go with the following code so far:

```
fifth_year = ['R-Sr.+', 'Sr.+', 'R-Sr.']
fourth_year = ['Sr.', 'R-Jr.']
third_year = ['Jr.', 'R-So.']
second_year = ['So.', 'R-Fr.']
first_year = ['Fr.']

roster_final.loc[(roster_final['Experience'] == 'R-Sr.+') | (roster_final['Experience'] == 'Sr.+') | (roster_final['Experience'] == 'R-Sr.'), 'Class'] = 'Fifth Year' 
roster_final.loc[(roster_final['Experience'] == 'Sr.') | (roster_final['Experience'] == 'R-Jr.'), 'Class'] = 'Fourth Year'
roster_final.loc[(roster_final['Experience'] == 'Jr.') | (roster_final['Experience'] == 'R-So.'), 'Class'] = 'Third Year'
roster_final.loc[(roster_final['Experience'] == 'So.') | (roster_final['Experience'] == 'R-Fr.'), 'Class'] = 'Second Year'
roster_final.loc[(roster_final['Experience'] == 'Fr.'), 'Class'] = 'First Year'

# roster_final['Class'] = roster_final['Experience'].apply(lambda x: 'fifth_year' if x.isin(fifth_year))


year5 = roster_final[['Number', 'Name', 'Position', 'Experience', 'Class']][roster_final['Class']=='Fifth Year']
year4 = roster_final[['Number', 'Name', 'Position', 'Experience', 'Class']][roster_final['Class']=='Fourth Year']
year3 = roster_final[['Number', 'Name', 'Position', 'Experience', 'Class']][roster_final['Class']=='Third Year']
year2 = roster_final[['Number', 'Name', 'Position', 'Experience', 'Class']][roster_final['Class']=='Second Year']
year1 = roster_final[['Number', 'Name', 'Position', 'Experience', 'Class']][roster_final['Class']=='First Year']

scholarship_roster = roster_final.groupby("Position")
scholarship_roster = scholarship_roster["Name"].apply(list)
scholarship_roster = scholarship_roster.reset_index()

year5[year5['Position'] == 'OL']
```

I can be able to break the first table down using groupbys and lists, but I want my result to look exactly like what was on [the aforementioned website.](https://www.roarlionsroar.com/penn-state-football/scholarship-grid) If there is anybody that can help me get to this output, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Your problem is a bit complex tbh. I would suggest you show the data structure you have, and think of how the data structure would look like that does what you want, then ask for the specific transformation to go from the first to the second.

Answer (score 1):

Does the code below generally answer the question?  It should give you an idea or at least some food for thought.

Note:

- Summing the names to the final row as grand totals per columns needs thinking about.
- The function `addYear(x)` probably needs checking as I didn't try to get the right year per string, just something for a demo.
- Just spotted: The `Year` column ordering is first to fifth but the example you provided it is seniors on the left (and words for 'Freshman' etc.).  However, you can easily reverse the ordering on line 54 of the code and (if required) change the wording of the values in the `Year` column in the `addYear` function when reviewing that (see first bullet above).

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

#set how the names of the players will be joined in the final pivot.  Pipe seems to work best
join_string = r' | '

# I could not get https://gopsusports.com/sports/football/roster/2021 to load but I saw this...
url = 'https://www.roarlionsroar.com/penn-state-football/roster'

page = requests.get(url)
table = pd.read_html(page.text, header = 1)
df_roster = table[0]
del df_roster['No.']

# df_roster['Class/Eligibility'].value_counts()

def addYear(x):
    '''
    df_roster['Class/Eligibility'].value_counts() returns the following:
    FR/FR 35, SO/FR 19, SR/JR 16, JR/SO 14, 
    SO/SO 7, JR/JR 6, SR/SR 5, 5th/SR 2, GR/SR 1
    '''
    if x == 'FR/FR':
        return 'First'
    elif x == 'SO/FR':
        return 'Second'
    elif x == 'SR/JR':
        return 'Fourth'
    elif x == 'JR/SO':
        return 'Third'
    elif x == 'SO/SO':
        return 'Second'
    elif x == 'JR/JR':
        return 'Third'
    elif x == 'SR/SR':
        return 'Fifth'
    elif x == '5th/SR':
        return 'Fifth'
    elif x == 'GR/SR':
        return 'Fifth'
    else:
        return 'Unknown'

df_roster['Year'] = df_roster['Class/Eligibility'].apply(addYear)

df_roster = df_roster[['Position', 'Year', 'Name']]

df_pivot = df_roster.pivot_table(index="Position", columns="Year", values="Name", \
                                 margins = True, aggfunc=lambda x: join_string.join(x), fill_value='-')

df_pivot = df_pivot.reindex(['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth'], axis=1)
df_pivot = df_pivot.reindex(['QB', 'RB', 'WR', 'TE', 'OL', 'DE', 'DT', 'LB', 'CB', 'S', 'K', 'P'], axis=0)

print(df_pivot)
```

**Output example:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much MDR. This is pretty close to what I was looking for. Is there a way to have every name visible in each column?

Comment: If you output the dataframe (eg, `df_pivot.to_html('scholarship_grid.html')`) you'll find they are all there.  The screenshot is an output that just truncates to keep the width/height reasonable.